# How can I find only the strings between `'`(with a minimum length) when there are multiple matches on a single line?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this regex:

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AJ3pAs/5)

```
'.{5,}'
```

It matches as desired only the strings from `key3` and `key4` here:

```
var obj1 = {
  key1: 'xxx',
  key2: 'xxxx',
  key3: 'xxxxx',
  key4: 'xxxxxx'
};
```

But if the object is on a single line it matches everything starting from first comma to the last one it finds:

```
var obj2 = { key1: 'xxx', key2: 'xxxx', key3: 'xxxxx', key4: 'xxxxxx' };
```

I want to repeat the same result from `obj1` on `obj2`.

Comment: Why are you parsing JavaScript with a regular expression?

Comment: `'.{5,}?'`, but depending on what you’re using this for, you might want to consider using [a JavaScript parser](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn).

Comment: a JavaScript parser only for this? It looks overkill.

Comment: @Phil. I do not parse JavaScript with regex. Is simply for my IDE to make it ignore the spellchecking for some long strings that are randomly generated ids. It annoys me to see those useless spell checking errors.

Comment: have you tried setting the multi line flag?

Comment: @Alqin: It isn't overkill, it's the way to go if you  want to write a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Finally!!!

`'\b[^']{5,}'`

https://regex101.com/r/AJ3pAs/10

Well, that was unnecssarily complex getting here :)

Why this works: `\b` marks word boundaries (between `\w` and `\W`). So this *requires* that your quotes always start with a `\w` character. An alternative with somewhat relaxed requirements would be a variant of another answer below (which also might work for you `'\S{5,}?'`. **None** of these solutions would work in a sense matching the javascript implementation of 'quote string boundaries', for which you'd need something kinda like what I was writing earlier.

#### previous

Here is a better match, this works but only if you can use capture groups. looking at converting the capture groups to exclusive captures now:

`'[^'\r\n]{1,4}'|('[^'\r\n]{5,}')`
https://regex101.com/r/AJ3pAs/8

This is getting interesting to me, because normally I would use capture groups like that and just work with the groups. bu there you need the actual match to work, right? So, a Lookbehind would make sense:
`(?<='[^'\r\n]{1,4}'.*?)('[^'\r\n]{5,}')` Howeer the problem there is it is not fixed width, and many regex engines including javascript require fixed width lookaround assertions. Still looking for a better solution for you.

#### original, incorrect attempt

try `'[^'\r\n]{5,}'` to match this. You could use `'[^']{5,}'` but that will not work on multiline text.

https://regex101.com/r/AJ3pAs/7

edit: ok, I see that was not accurate.

Comment: This works in the end the way I expected : `'\S{5,}?'`, because I have a `-` at the beginning of some strings.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How's about:

`'[\w0-9]{5,}?'`

This does a non-greedy match accepting only word or digit symbols. This will prevent matching on commas and colons.

Comment: that won't work if he has actual content in the quotation marks. specifically \s like 'xx xx'

Comment: The OP said they were id's - I don't expect spaces.

Comment: That's interesting... if so you should probably change it to \S, but that might work for his needs I dunno

Comment: Yeah, a lot depends on the characteristics of the values between quotes. He may need to do something that triggers off the leading ':', for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the regex is greedy and the dot causes all chars to be eaten, including single quotes, up to the last quote. Include all characters except the single quote (and the escape), that way it will stop at the first single quote.

For instance: `'[^']*'`

And then manually check each match's length so that it's 5 or more.

With escapes: `'([^'\\]|\\.)*'`

Answer (score 0):

Regex selectors like `*` or `{5,}`are *greedy* by default. That means if a match would work with more characters, it'll take more characters.

The dot `.` matches any character except a line break. So if there are at least two quotation marks on a line, your regex will match everything from the first one it finds to the last one it finds.

To make a selector non-greedy, you just need to put a `?` after it.

```
'.{5,}?'
```

However, this might not work well if you have escaped quote marks in a string, so you'll have to work a bit more on your regex.